# System.IndexOutOfRangeException in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I write `@Styles.Render("~/admin/scripts")`
in _Layout.cshtml on my project.I take "System.IndexOutOfRangeException".
What can I do.
This is my BundleConfig.cs file

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/admin/scripts")
            .Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")

            );
```

Comment: Why do you use style bundles for scripts? I think you should use `ScriptBundle` and `@Scripts.Render`.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't relaize it